# TypeScript argument type inference for a generic function argument with return?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a generic function that takes another function and infers the return type (similar to what map would do).

I have this code:

```
type game_selector<T> = <T>( state : GT.game_state ) => T

export function useGameState<T>( gs : game_selector<T> ): T {
```

And then I call it like this:

```
const users = useGameState( gs => gs.users )
```

I assume from the error, that type of `gs` is properly inferred, since it correctly finds the type of `gs.users` to be `Users`.  The error is:

```
TS2322: Type 'Users' is not assignable to type 'T'
```

How do I type this function correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unnecessary additional generic type here:

```
type game_selector<T> = <T>( state : GT.game_state ) => T;
```

The returned `T` is actually this one: `<T>(...)`, but I suspect you need the provided type from `game_selector<T>`.

If you try this in the Typescript playground you will actually see a slightly greyed out `T` in `game_selector<T>`. When you hover over it, it shows you a warning saying:

> 'T' is declared but its value is never read.(6133)

This will fix it for you:

```
type game_selector<T> = ( state : GT.game_state ) => T;
```

Comment: Indeed. The outer `T` is shadowed by the inner `T`.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize you don't need the <T> on type definitions, as I thought it'd be the same as an anonymous generic type.  This does what I want now.